# Oracle DB unix/linux autostart - oracle user no login shell

Tags: oracle, startup

I have to setup an autostart for a Oracle DB 12c on a RHEL 6.8 OS. The user oracle has no login shell e.g.

```
sudo su - oracle -s /bin/bash
```

I followed a [guide for a RHEL setup](https://www.krenger.ch/blog/automating-database-startup-and-shutdown-on-red-hat/). The init.d script Looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 35 99 10
# description: Starts and stops Oracle processes

ORA_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/12cR1/db
ORA_OWNER=oracle

PATH=${PATH}:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
HOST=`hostname`
PLATFORM=`uname`
export ORACLE_HOME PATH
case $1 in
'start')
        su - $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start"
        su - $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/dbstart"
        ;;
'stop')
        su - $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/lsnrctl stop"
        su - $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/dbshut"
        ;;
*)
        echo "usage: $0 {start|stop}"
        exit 1
esac
#
exit
```

After os reboot.  Oracle DB does not start. What could be wrong? Are there other logs beside $ORACLE_HOME/startup.log?

Comment: What happens, when you run the script manually as root? `/etc/init.d/oracle start`

Comment: /etc/init.d/oracle start LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 30-SEP-2016 09:15:29
Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started
ORACLE_HOME_LISTNER is not SET, unable to auto-start Oracle Net Listener
Usage: /opt/oracle/product/12cR1/db/bin/dbstart ORACLE_HOME
Processing Database instance "XXXX": log file /opt/oracle/product/12cR1/db/startup.log

Comment: Just for what it's worth, I _never_ set up my db's for autostart.  If my server has been shut down (planned or not) I want to check things out before I allow my databases to start.  Does that mean I sometimes have to log in from home in the wee hours? Sure.  But that kind of thing goes with the job for DBAs and SAs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The init.d script has to be modified by adding "-s /bin/bash" to the start and stop case. This should allow the oracle user to be login without the password.

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 35 99 10
# description: Starts and stops Oracle processes

ORA_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/12cR1/db
ORA_OWNER=oracle

PATH=${PATH}:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
HOST=`hostname`
PLATFORM=`uname`
export ORACLE_HOME PATH
case $1 in
'start')
        su - $ORA_OWNER -s /bin/bash -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start"
        su - $ORA_OWNER -s /bin/bash -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/dbstart"
        ;;
'stop')
        su - $ORA_OWNER -s /bin/bash -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/lsnrctl stop"
        su - $ORA_OWNER -s /bin/bash -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/dbshut"
        ;;
*)
        echo "usage: $0 {start|stop}"
        exit 1
esac
#
exit
```